# Настройка FastReport на Delphi XE - Fatal Error - Fatal Error: F2051 Unit RvDLDBX was compiled with a different version of SqlExpr.TSQLConnection

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, fastreport

Устанавливал FastReport по многочисленным, раздробленным инструкциям по установки из интернета. Всё пошагово скомпилировал, установил все его компоненты (обычного инсталятора не нашёл). Проверял открытием проекта - открыл, ошибок нет.
Но недавно нашли недочёт в ПО, стал компилировать проект и компилятор Delphi XE выдал Fatal Error:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] fs_ibdertti.pas(170): F2051 Unit RvDLDBX was compiled with a different version of SqlExpr.TSQLConnection
```

Как я понимаю, модуль RvDLDBX был скомпилирован с другой версией SqlExpr.TSQLConnection - но что это такое? Как его скомпилировать теперь с нужной версией и кто его компилировал? И вообще, как узнать нужную теперь версию SqlExpr.TSQLConnection?
Версию Delphi XE я не менял. Вероятно надо искать именно какую-то нужную версию FastReport и всё заново переустанавливать вручную, компилируя каждый компонент? А вдруг опять не та версия попадёт? Опять всё снова?
Есть ли решение данной проблемы?

Comment: https://www.fastreport.ru/ru/support/

Comment: Ответ один - переустанавливайте заново и именно под ту версию Делфы, что у вас стоит.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, боюсь с бесплатниками они общаться не станут.

Comment: У FastReport разве есть бесплатная версия? FreeReport (v2) уже не поддерживается, а для остальных только Trial и полная лицензия

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, была ведь, работало всё. Или 4-ая была или 5-ая (так как есть эти все версии в наличии, других у меня не было)